# How do I select all manager with respective employee

Tags: sql

```
ID  EMP_ID  EMP_NAE  MANAGER_ID
1     1      KARAN      2
2     2      K VEDI     3
3     3      SOMYA      2
4     4      KAVITA     3
5     5      AMAN       2
```

Comment: Is that your output expected, or your structure Table ? MySql or Sql-server ?

Comment: WE should re-open because it is clear what is being asked and this is actually a common confusion / question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list of employees and their managers use this:

```
select emp_nae as [Employee name], man.emp_nae as [Manager name]
from tablename as emp
left join tablename as man on man.emp_id = emp.manager_id
```

for a list of managers and thier employees use this:

```
select emp_nae as [Employee name], man.emp_nae as [Manager name]
from tablename as man
join tablename as emp on man.emp_id = emp.manager_id
```